# Model Mapper should only map first entry of list

Tags: java, modelmapper

I have the following Entities

```
public class Manufacturer
{
    int id;

    String name;

    Country country;

    List<Model> models;
}

public class Model
{
   int id;

   String name;
}
```

And the following DTO

```
public class ManufacturerLastModelDto
{
    Integer id;

    String name;

    ModelDto model;
}

public class ModelDto
{
   int id;

   String name;
}
```

Now I want to map the Manufacturer to the ManufacturerLastModelDto, like that:

```
modelMapper.map(manufacturer, ManufacturerLastModelDto.class)
```

So that only the first entry of the List model will be assigned from manufacturer.

My previous solution was that I had a List of ModelDto's even in the DTO and removed all Entries after Index 0. That was OK, because the ModelMapper mapped the child from Model to ModelDTO automatically.

But only Response wasn't so nice:

```
  models: [
    {...}
  ]
```

because it was sent as an Array.

Do I need a custom ModelMapper here? If so, how to build it? The tutorial is really complex. Do I need a converter or a TypeMap (or both)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not too familiar with ModelMapper but have used it occasionally.

Yes, you would need to create a converter for the property, and you could either use it with the ModelMapper or a TypeMap. Only caveat being that you will need to map the property yourself, for instance

The converter

```java
Converter<List<Model>, ModelDto> modelConverter = new AbstractConverter<List<Model>, ModelDto>() {
            @Override
            protected ModelDto convert(List<Model> models) {
                if (models == null || models.isEmpty()) {
                    return null;
                }
                Model model = models.get(0);
                ModelDto dto = new ModelDto();
                dto.setId(model.getId());
                dto.setName(model.getName());
                return dto;
            }
        };
```

Now using default model mapper

```java
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
modelMapper.addConverter(modelConverter);

ManufacturerLastModelDto result = modelMapper.map(manufacturer, ManufacturerLastModelDto.class);
```

Or using the TypeMap

```java
TypeMap<Manufacturer, ManufacturerLastModelDto> typeMap = modelMapper.typeMap(Manufacturer.class, ManufacturerLastModelDto.class)
                .addMappings(mapper ->
                        mapper.using(modelConverter).map(Manufacturer::getModels, ManufacturerLastModelDto::setModel)
                );

ManufacturerLastModelDto result = typeMap.map(manufacturer);
```